# python read input from file instead of user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a working python script that checks the vat number of European companies.
However checking 20 vat id by typing is not logical. I would like to check vat numbers from a file instead of manual typing every vat ids.

Here is the code:

```
from suds.client import Client
from urllib import getproxies
from pyfiglet import Figlet
import re 


custom_fig = Figlet(font='slant')
print(custom_fig.renderText('VATCheck'))

stringtosplit = raw_input('Enter vat number (like "EE102323452") :')
letters = ''.join(re.findall('([a-zA-Z])', stringtosplit))
numbers = ''.join(re.findall('([0-9])', stringtosplit))
VIES_URL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl"

client = Client(VIES_URL, proxy=getproxies())

response = client.service.checkVat(letters, numbers)

print (response)
```

How can i achieve to check several vat number from a **vat_numbers.txt** file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `vat_numbers.txt` file looks like:

```bash
EE102323452
EE102323453
EE102323454
```

Try the following:

```py
from suds.client import Client
from urllib import getproxies
from pyfiglet import Figlet
import re 


custom_fig = Figlet(font='slant')
print(custom_fig.renderText('VATCheck'))

#stringtosplit = raw_input('Enter vat number (like "EE102323452") :')
with open('vat_numbers.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for stringtosplit in handle:
        letters = ''.join(re.findall('([a-zA-Z])', stringtosplit))
        numbers = ''.join(re.findall('([0-9])', stringtosplit))
        VIES_URL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl"

        client = Client(VIES_URL, proxy=getproxies())

        response = client.service.checkVat(letters, numbers)

        print (response)
```

Comment: Is there any way to add description lines in txt file like; EE102323452 # Company name ?

Comment: You can put each record (with as many fields as required) in each line of the text. Separate them with a separator, such as `,` or `;`. While reading back, add the following line after the for loop: `record = stringtosplit.splt(,)`. Now this record is a list, use indexing to access each field.

Comment: i get error; File "vat.py", line 15
    record = stringtosplit.splt(,)
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: i put "record = stringtosplit.splt(,)" under; "numbers = ''.join(re.findall('([0-9])', stringtosplit))"

Comment: my bad, it was a typo, I meant: `record = stringtosplit.split(',')` (assuming the fields are separated by a `,` in your file). Place it right under the for loop. Then get each field using `record[i]` where `i` is index of the field. Then perform your desired processing.